# No implementations provided for the following modules

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm having a problem with `corebuild`. I have written the following program:

```
open Core.Std
open Smtp

type person = {
  name: string;
  address: Smtp_unix.Addr.t
}

let send p1 p2 =
  Smtp_unix.sendmail ~host:"gmail.google.fr"
    ~name:"gmail.google.com"
    ~from:(Smtp_unix.Addr.of_string "<hidden>")
    ~to_:[p1.address]
    ~body:("Hello "^p2.name)
    ()

let () =
  let p1 = {name="alice"; address = Smtp_unix.Addr.of_string "alice@example.com"} in
  let p2 = {name="bob"; address = Smtp_unix.Addr.of_string "bob@example.com"} in
  match send p1 p2 with
  | `Ok _ -> printf "Mail sent"
  | `Failure (_,m) -> printf "Error: %s" m
```

which according to `Merlin` is correct. To compile it, I run the following command

```
corebuild example.native -package smtp
```

and I get the following error, which I don't understand.

```
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Smtp_unix referenced from example.cmx
```

I don't get what is wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like smtp_unix is needed for smtp.

```
corebuild send.native -package smtp.unix -package smtp
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could do that kinda thing. Where am I supposed to find the structure of a package?

Comment: I do not know if there is tool for this. What I did is that I used utop and tried your code. then I tried to add new libraries (using #require directive and the list of available libs given at the bottom of utop - looking for libs starting by s). So not rocket science, but it helps ;)